# Add vertical expand/collapse (accordian) in ng-grid individual row

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accordion, ng-grid

I have a very long text in one of the columns in an ng-grid. If the text overflows the cell it puts the elipsis at the end. 
What I am trying to do is finding some good way of showing the large text to the user. 
I tried following things:

1.) Tool tip
2.) Dialog popup

But none of the looked very good as the text is not marked i.e., no styling. I was showing the text as it is.

Currently I am trying to have a way to expand and collapse the particular cell or the whole row. I tried to change the styling from the debugger but no change in the view even it show that the height of the cell and row has been changed.

So what I want is to to have a way of showing the long text(30-35 lines) nicely to the user or making it expand/collapse way.

Please help.

Comment: You can try to use a scroll, jscrollpane for example

Answer (score 1):

I made a plunker to show how you could create a horizontal scroll bar in the cell:
http://plnkr.co/edit/jmt4WidX2P6QfNokqdGP?p=preview

I used this style for the cell template:

```
.scrollingDiv {
  overflow:auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I think for 35 lines of text, you might be better off showing the content in a detail pane below the grid, wired up to the cell selection.